# Find 1st occurrence of a string preceding a line in a file

Tags: python

I have a file formatted as:

```
$ORIGIN .com.rpz.my.azure_domain.com
azurebox1   CNAME   azurebox1-dr.my.azure_domain.com
$ORIGIN rpz.my.aws_domain.com
awsbox1     CNAME   awsbox1-dr.my.aws_domain.com
awsbox2     CNAME   awsbox2-dr.my.aws_domain.com
awsbox3     CNAME   awsbox3-dr.my.aws_domain.com
$ORIGIN .org.rpz.my.gc_domain.com
gcbox1      CNAME   gcbox1-dr.my.gc_domain.com
gcbox2      CNAME   gcbox1-dr.my.gc_domain.com
```

For each line containing a cname record, I need to append the rpz entry for its preceding $ORIGIN value. So the first column of the my.gc_domain.com CNAMES becomes:

```
gcbox1.org.rpz.my.gc_domain.com
gcbox2.org.rpz.my.gc_domain.com
```

AWS would look like:

```
awsbox1.rpz.my.aws_domain.com
awsbox2.rpz.my.aws_domain.com
awsbox3.rpz.my.aws_domain.com
```

I'm reading the file as:

```
f = open('current_records', 'r')
records_string = f.readlines()
```

How do I find the preceding $ORIGIN line and its rpz.* substring without also capturing every single $ORIGIN line in the file?

Comment: You're thinking of this the wrong way. Don't find the preceding `$ORIGIN`. Read the file line by line, and if it begins with `$ORIGIN` save the value in a variable. Then append that variable to all the other lines.

Comment: Why would it? The variable always contains the last origin.

Comment: Each time you get to another origin you update the variable, and use that for the following lines in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the file line by line and update the value of a variable `origin` as soon as a new `$ORIGIN` line is encountered.

Also there are some little adjustments that I'll address by commenting the relevant instructions.

```
# read the file
# use the with open scope instead of directly reading the file, so that you won't have to close the stream after.
with open("current_records") as f:  # no need for 'r' mode, it's default
    records = f.readlines()

# iterate through the list of records and their position indices
# we will need to index the list to replace a CNAME line, since strings are immutable
origin = "" # this will hold the $ORIGIN string
for n, record in enumerate(records):
    # if we encounted an $ORIGIN record, we update the variable
    if record.startswith("$ORIGIN"):
        origin = record.split()[1]
    # otherwise, we replace the CNAME value accordingly
    else:
        # build cname string
        cname = record.split()[0] + origin
        records[n] = record.replace("CNAME", cname)

# re-build the file and write it
with open("new_records", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(records))  # join updated lines interposing new lines between them
```

This should produce a new file with the same structure and the updated `CNAME` 'fields'.

It should be noted that this solution won't work if you cannot expect the file structure to be exactly the same. Also, you might need to deal with any extra whitespaces that I couldn't see clearly in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

data = {}
with open('current_records') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('$ORIGIN'):
            curr_type = line[8:]
            data[curr_type] = []
        else:
            data[curr_type].append(line[20:])

out = [[re.sub(r'(\w+)(.*)', r'\1', x)+key for x in value] for key, value in data.items()]
print(out)

# Output:
[['azurebox1.com.rpz.my.azure_domain.com'], ['awsbox1rpz.my.aws_domain.com', 'awsbox2rpz.my.aws_domain.com', 'awsbox3rpz.my.aws_domain.com'], ['gcbox1.org.rpz.my.gc_domain.com', 'gcbox1.org.rpz.my.gc_domain.com']]
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing here please?